# QTcpSocket + QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Доброго дня! 
Есть устройство с которого нужно считывать строку в ACSII протокол общения TCP/IP. Есть рабочий код:

```
QString tmp;
QByteArray bytes = m_TcpSocket->readAll();
tmp.append(bytes);
ui->textEdit->append(tmp);
// На выходе получаем строку: "22N00001CPZL59OMX3G3TG7710140010062586CG9P6KDCZSBDNT7GFQPA1ERDT63X36"
```

Но, везде указывают что нужен QDataStream "Класс незаменимым для обмена данными по сети с использованием сокетных соединений." Как я не пытался, я не могу получить через него заветную строчку, как в коде выше. 
Варианты которые я попробовал:

```
QString tmp; 
QByteArray bytes = m_pTcpSocket->readAll();
QDataStream out(&bytes, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);
out >> tmp;
ui->textEdit->append(tmp);
//Получаю пустую строчку.
```

Вариант 2( из книги Шлее М. Qt5.3):

```
QDataStream in(m_TcpSocket);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);
for(;;){
    if(!m_BlockSize) {
        if(m_TcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)){
            break;
        }
        in >> m_BlockSize;
    }

    if(m_TcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_BlockSize){
        break;
    }

    QString str;
    in >> str;
    ui->textEdit->append(str);
    m_BlockSize = 0;
}
```

Доходит до if(m_TcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_BlockSize) и дальше не идет, а если пустить дальше, то всё равно пустая строка на выходе. 
Подскажите, чего не хватает для работы с QDataStream?

Comment: Я не понял. Если есть рабочий код, дающий правильный результат, зачем пытаться в него добавить что-то еще, что к тому же его ломает?

Comment: Я не знаю, правильно ли я делаю. Так как все примеры используют QDataStream

Comment: Я бы поспорил с уважаемым Шлее, QDataStream предназначен для сериализации бинарных данных платформонезависимым способом. Если у вас нет необходимости для обмена данными между различными платформами и архитектурами (например BE и LE, Windows <=> Solaris), то нет нужды использовать громоздкий QDataStream. Сами по себе сокеты обмениваются байтами, поэтому прием входящих данных в QByteArray выглядит более логичным. Так что ваш первый вариант вполне себе рабочий и правильный.

Comment: Единственное, для более правильного чтения данных из сокета лучше организовать цикл чтения с неким контролем целостности передачи. Например все сообщения кодируются в Base64, а разделителем между сообщениями служит байт 0х00. Тогда принимающая сторона в цикле будет принимать данные до появления 0 байта, как только 0й байт получен, можно обработать сообщение целиком, очистить приемный буфер и дальше продолжать прием данных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Почитаю как сделать контроль целостности.